# Error while loading shared libraries:libmc_data.so.1

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

I can not run C++ code,because I got

```
Error while loading shared libraries:libmc_data.so.1:cannot open shared object file:No such file or directory
```

But with ls I got

```
milenko@milenko-HP-Compaq-6830s:~/ProcMT64/old/version_september_2015/bin$ ls -l libmc_data.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 milenko milenko 19 Set 19 07:36 libmc_data.so.1 -> libmc_data.so.1.0.0
```

What's the problem here?

Comment: Try this command first: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/ProcMT64/old/version_september_2015/bin

Comment: @Marco With cd I go to bin directory where this library is.So i do not know how to search for the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the linux loader will look for libraries in several predefined locations plus the directories listed in the env variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH (man ld for more information). Try adding the directory ~/ProcMT64/old/version_september_2015/bin to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH by running:

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:~/ProcMT64/old/version_september_2015/bin

and run your application, it should work (unless other libraries are missing ..)